# CSV Upload to mySQL error with isset

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Below is the current script I'm working on which should take a csv file uploaded by a user and insert it into mySQL. I got the connection working, but I keep getting a server error as soon as I add the isset($_POST). I'd really appreciate some help if you see anything that might be causing the issue.

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to Database";

if(isset($_POST)['submit']))
{
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    while((fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false)
    {
        $storenumber = $fileop[0];
        $zipcode = $fileop[1];
        $sales = $fileop[2];

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (store_number,zip_code,sales) VALUES('$storenumber','$zipcode','$sales')");
    }
    if($sql)
    {
        echo 'data uploaded';
    }
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's formatted incorrectly

change `if(isset($_POST)['submit']))` to `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Answer (score 0):

if (isset ($_POST['submit']))

Just a parenthesis problem ;)